# Core Data migration with empty tables inside DB

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

I wanted to create migration from Transformable to String. I created mapping model and entity policy

```
class MigrationPolicy15to16: NSEntityMigrationPolicy {
    
    @objc
    func convertIntArrayToString(forValue: Any) -> String {
        guard let array = forValue as? [Int] else { return "[]" }
        
        return array.toJSONString()
    }
 
}
```

```
FUNCTION($entityPolicy, "convertIntArrayToStringForValue:" , $source.categories)
```

It works, migration successes. But on some devices it doesn't happen. I found a device where this happens and found that tables inside DB model are empty. There no records in DB at all. But migration fails with following error:

```
CoreData: annotation: (migration) inferring mapping model failed with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134190 "(null)" UserInfo={entity=EntityName, property=categories, reason=Source and destination attribute types are incompatible} userInfo: {
    entity = EntityName;
    property = categories;
    reason = "Source and destination attribute types are incompatible";
}
```